# Adding a bootstrap glyphicon to a button in rails

Tags: ruby, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to add a user glyphicon to my login input box in a rails app i am currently using Rails 4.2.3 and Ruby 2.2.0

I have tried to search this for quite some time but have not found how to add this to a rails app and would like my code to remain ruby as much as possible and if at all possible (if not i suppose html will suffice but i would LOVE to learn how to do this in rails syntax.

any help would be appreciated.

my input field looks like this so far.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
</div>
```

I would aslo like the glyph to appear on the Left and the placeholder on the Right of the input box if possible.

Comment: `<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></div>` use this as logout

Comment: that only puts it outside of the text field i am looking for a way to place it inside the text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= button_tag raw("<i class='srch-control-icon-srch'></i> search"), class: "button round" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"> <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out">

    </span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/oLxxz9h4/1/)